# Renaming xml based on tag

Tags: xml, bash, shell

I have a number of xml files. I need to rename each based on the specific tag (say `tag1="alpha"`) inside the xml.

I have figured out how to rename the file based on *single* occurance of the specific tag.

```bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.xml' -exec /rename.sh {} \;
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash

tag1=$(sed 's/.*tag1="\([^"]*\).*/\1/; q' "$1")
mv -v "$1" "$tag1.xml"
```

The problem: some files have multiple `tag1` tags, e.g. `tag1="alpha"` `tag1="beta"` `tag1="omega"`. With these files I need to also create a copies of the same file, but with the other names, `beta.xml`, `omega.xml`.

I tried to cat with positional parameters but that didn't work (I am a beginner).

**file structure example:**

```xml
<div class="div-entry">
 <d:entry xmlns:d="http://www.apple.com/DTDs/DictionaryService-1.0.rng" id="m_en_gbus0022390" tag1="Alhambra" class="entry">
   <span class="hg x_xh0">
     <span role="text" d:syl="1" homograph="1" class="hw">Al.ham.bra<d:syl/><span class="gp ty_hom tg_hw">1 </span></span>
     <span prxid="Alhambra_us_x" prlexid="pron0091531.002" dialect="AmE" class="prx"> | <span d:prn="US" id="m_en_gbus0022390.007" dialect="AmE" class="ph t_respell">alˈ;hambre;<d:prn/></span><span d:prn="IPA" id="m_en_gbus0022390.007" soundFile="alhambra#1_us_1" media="online" dialect="AmE" class="ph">&#593;lˈ;h&#593;mbre;<d:prn/></span> | </span>
   </span>
   <span class="sg">
     <span id="m_en_gbus0022390.003" class="se1 x_xd0">
       <span id="m_en_gbus0022390.004" class="msDict x_xd1 t_core">
         <span role="text" class="fg">
           <span class="gp tg_fg">(</span>
           <span tag1="the Alhambra"></span>
           <span class="gp tg_fg">) </span>
         </span>
         <span d:def="1" role="text" class="df">a fortified Moorish palace, the last stronghold of the Muslim kings of Granada, built between 1248 and 1354 near Granada in Spain<span class="gp tg_df">. </span><d:def/></span>
       </span>
     </span>
   </span>
 </d:entry>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the name of the element with this attribute? An example xml file would be useful.

Comment: @Shawn Example added.

Comment: It's invalid XML...

Comment: In addition to not having a root tag, there's stuff like `<span tag1="cudgels", <span tag1="cudgeling"<span class="pr"/>, <span tag1="cudgeled"<span class="pr"/>`

Comment: @glennjackman @Shawn Fixed the XML example. I know I would be better off to use something like xmlstarlet, but this works for my present purposes. Just need improve upon my code to account for multiple `tag1` tags. I thought I can somehow use `cat` with positional parameters?

Comment: The xml is still riddled with errors (missing `>` on the span tags). You need to make it easier for people who want to help you. And most people who want to help you will tell you to use an XML parser for XML data.

Comment: @glennjackman Now the XML is valid, no?

Comment: No. `<span tag1="the Alhambra"</span>` and the opening 2 divs are not closed

Comment: Look at the line with the span `tag1="the Alhambra"` -- are there enough closing angle brackets on that line?

Comment: @glennjackman I see. Fixed XML, better? I know I should use proper XML parser, I was just hoping that my first code can be modified to accomodate multiple tags. Appreciate your help anyway!

Comment: See, this is why you need to at least validate the XML. You'd know these errors existed without having ask each time.

Comment: Right! Before I did some regex and forgot to close the first tag. My bad. Now it should be all right.

Answer (score 2):

OK, now we have:

```bash
$ xmlstarlet validate file.xml
file.xml - valid
```

So we can extract the tag values

```bash
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v //@tag1 -n file.xml
Alhambra
the Alhambra
```

And store them in a bash array

```bash
$ readarray -t tag1 < <(xmlstarlet sel -t -v //@tag1 -n file.xml)
$ declare -p tag1
declare -a tag1=([0]="Alhambra" [1]="the Alhambra")
```

and renaming looks like:

```bash
for tag in "${tag1[@]}"; do
  cp -v "$1" "$tag.xml"
done
rm -v "$1"
```

Comment: I don't think `cp a b c d e` will copy a to each of b,c,d,e